# cannot get selected text with Nightwatch.js

Tags: javascript, nightwatch.js, e2e-testing

I want to test selected text value. Nightwatch.js API has elementActive() to get active element:

```
client.elementActive(function (result) {
    console.log(result);
});
```

It gives me:

```
{ state: 'success',
  sessionId: 'bc0b1b932cf8dac815bc8f1d94128a3c0d0278bd',
  hCode: 16988771,
  value: { ELEMENT: '2' },
  class: 'org.openqa.selenium.remote.Response',
  status: 0 }
```

How can I get the selected text?

Answer (score 0):

Do something like this

```
      browser.elementIdText(ELEMENT, (text) => {
          console.log('text ', text);
        }
```